# Using bit masking to set 0 to 1 and everything else to 0

Tags: unsigned, bitmask

How could I use bit masking to make all the bits in a number 1 if they were all 0, and all 0 if they were not?

Using an unsigned variable:

So, if I have `0000-0000`, I would like that to become `1111-1111`.
If I have `0101-0110` (or `0000-0001`, or `1111-1111`, etc), I would like that to become `0000-0000`.

Is this possible to do without using any conditional?

Comment: What language? Also, "0000-0000" looks like a string, not an unsigned integer.. In any case, look at the documentation in your language for bit complement (~ in C/C++).

Comment: I put 0000-0000 for readability...

Comment: So basically you want this code without the "if"?:  `if value == 0: result = 255; else: result = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it's possible:

```
int y = 0xff;
y = ~(y & 1 | y>>1 & 1 | y>>2 & 1 | ...) - 1
```

But unless this is an academic exercise, you really shouldn't. If you're concerned about performance, `y = y != 0` is almost certainly faster.

Explanation:

`y & 1` takes the first bit of the number. `y >> k` shifts the number right by `k` bits, allowing us to get that bit by `y >> k & 1`. We simply `|` them together, which results in one if any bit is set or zero if not. Subtracting 1 gives us 0 if any bit was set, and -1 if not. The binary representation of -1 is `1111...`

Shift:

```
1010 - y
1010 - y >> 0
 101 - y >> 1
  10 - y >> 2
   1 - y >> 3
```

Take the first bit:

```
   0 - y >> 0 & 1
   1 - y >> 1 & 1
   0 - y >> 3 & 1
   1 - y >> 4 & 1
```

Or them:

```
   1 - 0 | 1 | 0 | 1
```

Negate:

```
0000 - 1-1
```

Comment: Could you perhaps walk through what's going on here?

Comment: OK, I've added some explanation.

Comment: Also saw that you want all bits one, not just the first, so I updated for that too.

Answer (score 2):

Not in an efficient way probably.

If you really want you can maybe:

```
int mask = 0;
int result = 0;


for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(number) * 8; i++)
{
    mask |= number & 1 << i;
}


for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(number) * 8; i++)
{
    result |= mask & 1 << i;
}
```

~result is your answer.

Comment: The for loops use conditionals. Although I get what you are doing and the conditionals are not an integral part of the operation.

Comment: I'm sorry. Not trying to be. This is accurate and easy to understand.

Comment: Presumably you mean `sizeof(number) * 8`, since `sizeof` is bytes and you want to loop over every bit?

Comment: I meant it as in "size of the number in bits", you are right that the i was wrong, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def check_for_zero(value):
    # Same as "if value == 0: return 0; else: return 1"
    # value must be an 8-bit number.

    # Need to check all 8 bits of value.  But we can compress it...
    x = value | (value >> 4)
    # Now just need to check the low 4 bits of x.  Compress again...
    x = x | (x >> 2)
    # Now just need to check the low 2 bits of x.  Compress again...
    x = x | (x >> 1)
    # Now just need to check the low 1 bit of x.  Success!
    return x & 1

def expand_to_8bit(bit):
    # Same as "if bit == 0: return 0; else: return 255"
    # Must pass bit == 0 or bit == 1

    # bit is a 1-bit value.  Expand it...
    x = bit | (bit << 1)
    # x is a 2-bit value.  Expand it...
    x = x | (x << 2)
    # x is a 4-bit value.  Expand it...
    x = x | (x << 4)
    # x is a 8-bit value.  Done!
    return x

def foo(value):
    x = check_for_zero(value)
    x = x ^ 1  # Flips the bit
    return expand_to_8bit(x)
```

Comment: Sorry. I may have been misleading when I replied that "just no if statement" was correct. I don't want any conditional whatsoever. There should be no check on the value of the number.

Comment: The only checks are the "assert" statements, which you can take out.  They're just there so if you pass 1000000 to this code, it blows up obviously rather than doing the wrong thing.

Comment: OK, I removed the asserts for clarity.